# ng-checked event for checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to use ng-checked for checkbox under ng-repeat.

```
<div class="listing" ng-repeat="item in list>
<input type="checkbox" class="favor" ng-checked='::isFavorite(item)' ng-click='setFavorite(item)'/>
</div>
```

There is one method, which I am calling on ng-checked event. But, if there are 50 checkboxes in the list (i.e. 50 items in ng-repeat), then each time the page is drawn, the same method gets called twice an item. Any help would be really appreciable.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good if you declare JSON object in the controller for each item.

**JS**

```
list=[{name:'Item1',checked:true},{name:'Item2',checked:false}];
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="listing" ng-repeat="item in list>
  <input type="checkbox" class="favor" ng-checked='item.checked' ng-click='setFavorite(item)'/> {{item.name}}
</div>
```